# Problems with a Python script using xlwt

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwt

I am working on a Python script that would take the data from two sheets in Excel and would put data to a second Excel file according to the criteria in an if statement

```
for row_index in range(sheet2.nrows):
    name = sheet2.cell(row_index, 0).value
    names = name.split(',')
    if len(names) == 3:
        print names[1].lstrip(), names[0]
        for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
            if names[0] and names[1].lstrip() and names[2] in sheet1.cell(i, 4).value:
                sheetW.write(i, 0, sheet1.cell(i, 0).value)
                sheetW.write(i, 4, sheet1.cell(i, 4).value)
                sheetW.write(i, 1, names)
```

It should put the names only in the rows where the names variable matches with the column 4 in sheet1, however, it populates the whole column in the writable file with the last name in the iteration regardless of whether the name should go in that row or not. Could anybody help me figure out why?

Comment: You're looping over all rows in `sheet1` for every row in `sheet2` and if the criteria is met, writing it to the output sheet with a row index of `i`... That seems sus. to me...

Comment: In 'sheet2' there is a list of all individuals and their details. For every individual I want to iterate through the list in 'sheet1' to see if it is there. If it is, I want the script to put the details in that row in 'sheetW'. Everything seems right to me, however I can't fix the bug described above.

Comment: Where a row in sheet2 matches multiple rows in sheet1 - what's supposed to happen then? Same with what happens if multiple sheet1 rows match multiple sheet2 rows?

Comment: I understand that you are asking about the nested if statement. It is taking the value from the cell in column 0 and column 4 of the row i and puts it in the same position in the second excel file that is sheetW. It also takes the current matched names(list with first name and second name) and puts them in row i column 1.

Comment: I get that... let me try to explain in another way... let's say there's two rows in both sheets. Sheet2 row 1, matches Sheet1 rows 1 and 2, and Sheet2 row 2, matches Sheet1 rows 1 and 2... What do you get/expect?

Comment: I expect the data from Sheet2 to be copied into the appropriate cells of sheetW, the exact same ones as in the sheet1. However, even thought there is an if statement that should check for that, it still copies the last name in sheet2 to every row of column 1 of sheet1.